# What is the most appropriate way for masking in loss functions in PyTorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, loss-function

The target values look something like this:

```
y = tensor([[10.3, -1, -1, 4.5, 6.7, -1]])
```

and the predicted values from the network look something like this:

```
y_hat = tensor([[13.1, 12, 4.2, 6.2, 3.2, 10.1]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<ReluBackward0>)
```

I would like to evaluate the mean square error only for those elements which are not equal to -1 in tensor `y` without losing track of the gradients.

In essence, I would like the loss to be:

```
loss = (1/3)*sqrt((13.1-10.3)^2 + (6.2-4.5)^2 + (3.2-6.7)^2)
```

What is the most appropriate way of evaluating a loss like this?